# Simple rail fence decipher

Tags: python

I was tasked to create an encryption using a simple technique. I am struggling to create the second half that would decipher the message.

```
phrase = 'It is a period of civil war'
odd = ''
even = ''

for i,ch in enumerate(phrase):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        even += ch
    else:
        odd += ch

ciphertext = even + odd
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us what you've attempted so far?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I was able to create the message and I know that the correct way to do it is to reverse the steps, currently i split the message but i am confused on how to print every other letter to print the original message

Answer (score 1):

Before I get to the solution, always make sure you give your thoughts on the difficulty you're facing & exactly specify where you're having a problem. 

Currently, based on your code, it seems that your key for rail fence encryption is 2. Make sure to mention that in your code or description somewhere.


Anyway, if you analyze the ciphertext, we can reconstruct the original text back by first dividing the ciphertext into two parts and then appending the respective characters of the first part with that of the second part. So for this example, `I sapro fcvlwrti  eido ii a` is the ciphertext. Divide it into two equal (or nearly equal) parts, `I sapro fcvlwr` & `ti  eido ii a` Now just go on appending first character from the first half and second character from the second half. You just need to handle the case when the ciphertext is odd or even.

```
def decipher(ciphertex):
    originalText = ''
    size = len(ciphertext)

    for i in range((size)//2):
        originalText  += ciphertext[i] + ciphertext[size//2 + i + (size%2)]

    if(size%2==1):
        originalText += ciphertext[size//2]

    return originalText
```